# Correct use of Popen in Python, or something alike

Tags: python, popen

I'm completely new to Python,  and now I've to change a script so it calls another program and get it's  output. I've researched, and all the solutions point to something like

```
p = sub.Popen('echo '+s+' | ${morphg_res:-./morphg.ix86_linux -t}', shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE )
out,err=p.communicate()
print out
```

but I couldn't get it to work. "print out" prints nothing.

I had it working with

```
 os.system('echo '+s+' | ${morphg_res:-./morphg.ix86_linux -t}')
```

but this way I can't get the output of morphg.

Also, I don't exactly understand what the second part means, but I know it calls the program ccorrectly. Just that the output is to stdin, and I need it to be in a variable.

Any help?

P.S.: subprocess.check_output is not an option as I have Python 2.6.

Comment: It's generally considered to be a bad idea to use "shell=True" and to pass command strings to Popen (for the same reason that use of os.system() and the older popen*() functions are discouraged.  It's unsafe in that there are a number of ` (back tick) and $() (command substitution) and other strings which can be interpolated into a command to cause unintended consequences).  It's best to leave shell=False (the default) and pass a list (vector): ['echo', s ] --- though you'd then have to set up multiple processes and arrange the piping yourself for this example.

Comment: I had read that, but I have no idea how to do that.=P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import os
p = os.popen('echo '+s+' | ${morphg_res:-./morphg.ix86_linux -t}')
out = p.read()
print out
```